# To count a time of program execution that includes console input, in Python 3

Tags: python, time

For example, there is a program that is designed to do something with data inserted via Run Console. Something like this:

The program counts a number of actions necessary to make the number of elements in each container equal by adding 1 element to `k` containers, starting from the first one. If it is impossible, output is `-1`. `n` is a number of containers, `a` is an amount of elements in each container.

```
n = int(input())
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
i = 1
k = 1
actions = 0
while i < n:
    if a[i] < a[i - 1]:
        actions = -1
        break
    elif a[i] == a[i - 1]:
        i += 1
        k += 1
    elif a[i] > a[i - 1]:
        for j in range(k):
            a[j] += 1
            j += 1
        actions += 1
print(actions)
```

I have some problem with time limit of execution, as numbers in `a` are limited by 10**9, and my time limit is 2 seconds only. So I've decided to count the execution time, to watch its behaviour with different variables.

But all the methods I found to count the program execution time include the time to input in Run Console. And, you know, I can think for a number of seconds which data to input this time; so I need to count only the time of calculation, without the time of input.
Does anyone know how to implement that?

P.S.: if someone gives me a tip on how to make the program mentioned above not to count for months with the input like:

```
5
1 100 800 90000 1000000
```

I will be sincerely grateful.

Comment: Put your `start = now()` code after the input. It's that easy.

Comment: @iBug, do you mean using datetime.now()?

Comment: Anything like that. `time.time()` is also an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this  code

```
import datetime

n = int(input())
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
start_time = datetime.now()
i = 1
k = 1
actions = 0
while i < n:
    if a[i] < a[i - 1]:
        actions = -1
        break
    elif a[i] == a[i - 1]:
        i += 1
        k += 1
    elif a[i] > a[i - 1]:
        for j in range(k):
            a[j] += 1
            j += 1
        actions += 1
print(actions)
print(datetime.now() - start_time)  # time consumed on run
```

Comment: 1. Some explanation would be better. A big chunk of code without explanation would be hard for future readers to understand. 2. Does this code run or does it hit `AttributeError`?

Comment: The method with datetime.now() worked well.
Now the problem is to make my code run quicker, to make it confine into 2 seconds.
I get it as I have to refuse using a nested cycle, but I can't come up with an alternative.

Comment: Still, thank you both for solving the timecount problem.